I'm having problems with importing next/image and next/link
None of my next/ imports are working. I currently am using Next.js v14.2.4 and Node v18.17.0. On my "/app/page.tsx", I have these two imports:
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

In the return statement for export default function Page(), those two are called like this:
<Link
            href="/login"
            className="flex items-center gap-5 self-start rounded-lg bg-blue-500 px-6 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-colors hover:bg-blue-400 md:text-base"
          >
            <span>Log in</span> <ArrowRightIcon className="w-5 md:w-6" />
          </Link>

and
<Image
        src="/hero-desktop.png"
        width={1000}
        height={760}
        className="hidden md:block"
        alt="Screenshots of the dashboard project showing desktop version"
      />

The imports are highlighted red, and the error says
Cannot find module 'next/image'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

and the same thing for 'next/link'
I am following along on the official Next.js guide on the Learn section. I got the codes directly from the website
I have tried uninstalling Next.js, Node, restarting my VS code etc. I tried looking into using next/legacy/image, but it doesn't work either
I tried "npm i next/image" directly and it said permission denied
I made sure the images were under the /public folder // the tree structure is correct
Does anyone know what the issue is that I can't import these modules? I checked node_modules and I don't see them under the Next folder either.
If I could get some insights/way to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you

Some parts of the project might be corrupted. I will try running 'npm install' again and then retry.

next/image is a JS file that's shipped with the next package. If you can find node_modules/next/image.js, then this isn't the issue.
Secondly, double-check your tsconfig.json file in the root of your NextJS project. Make sure "moduleResolution" is set to "bundler", like so:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...other options
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Try running the app with npm run dev again and see if this resolves the issue.

I couldn't find node_modules/next/image.js. Can you suggest a solution based on that?

Can you try running rm -rf node_modules and then rerun your package installer (npm install or yarn install for example) and let me know if any errors pop up?

When I run npm i again after manually deleting node_modules, it says it was successful, but then I can't find "node_modules" under my file structures

If you're on MacOS or Linux, does node_modules show up when you run ls (or dir in Command Prompt on Windows)? If so, can you try restarting your code editor once more? Sometimes they can be a bit slow to update when new directories are created from the terminal.
If it still doesn't show up, check which directory you ran npm i in. You should be running it from the same directory where your package.json is.
